# Which command in my script is producing a syntax error?

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to create a little game with a batch file but it doesn't work, after displaying the block of instructions to the user, the user presses a key and then this error is printed:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

This is the full output:

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 welcome to battle ships! this is the imaginary grid.
 in this simplified version of the game, you only sink an CPUs ships, but dont place your own...
 if you shoot outside of the grid, it WILL count as a shot. you have only limited shots, so be careful
 please allow some time while the game is set up.
Press any key to continue . . .
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I do not understand which command is not correct, this is the entire script:

```
@echo off
echo     a
echo     b
echo     c
echo     d
echo     e
echo     f
echo     g
echo     h
echo     i
echo      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
echo  welcome to battle ships! this is the imaginary grid.
echo  in this simplified version of the game, you only sink an CPUs ships, but dont place your own...
echo  if you shoot outside of the grid, it WILL count as a shot. you have only limited shots, so be careful
echo  please allow some time while the game is set up.
pause

:ship one
set /a shiponey=%RANDOM% %%10
set /a shiponex=%RANDOM% %%10

if shiponey==1
set /a shiponey=a
goto ship two

if shiponey==2
set /a shiponey=b
goto ship two

if shiponey==3
set /a shiponey=c
goto ship two

if shiponey==4
set /a shiponey=d
goto ship two

if shiponey==5
set /a shiponey=e
goto ship two

if %shiponey%==6
set /a shiponey=f
goto ship two

if shiponey==7
set /a shiponey=g
goto ship two

if shiponey==8
set /a shiponey=h
goto ship two

if shiponey==9
set /a shiponey=i

set /a shots=20

shoot
set /p shoty=y coord (letter):
set /p shotx=x coord (number):
if %shoty%==%shiponey%
if %shotx%==%shiponex%
goto win

echo miss!
set /a shots==%shots%-1
echo you have %shots% shots left
if %shots%==0
goto lose

goto shoot


:lose
cls
echo you lose
pause

:win
cls
echo you win!!!!!!!!
pause
```

Comment: You have many `goto ship two` statements in your code, but no ship two target. Where do you expect the code to go when you've sent it into never-never land? Also, you shouldn't have spaces in `goto `targets - you should use `shipone` and `shiptwo` instead. You also have a `goto shoot`, but forgot to make `:shoot` a goto target. It's better if you write less code, test those smaller parts, and then slowly add more in smaller chunks, instead of cramming a bunch of untested code together somewhat randomly and hoping that it works.

Comment: Ken White is correct that small incremental changes will make it easier for you to debug your code, however you can also insert a lot of `echo` statements that can assist. I would suggest that while you are developing this batch, add an echo into each tag and if block until you are confident that the block does what you are expecting

Comment: None of the IF commands are valid syntax. Dead positive you never read the help file for the IF command. Open up a command prompt and type `IF /?`

Comment: First two rules of debugging a batch file. 1) Don't use `echo off` 2) Execute the batch file from the command prompt instead of using your mouse. This way you can read the error message and see what line of code it stopped executing.

Comment: @Squashman I would instead recommend turning echo on _only_ for the blocks of code that you need to debug, this is a small script, but echoing out _all_ the lines is not likely to help OP a great deal.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller if the user does not know where the mistake is how would they know where to use echo on?

Comment: @Squashman Don't use `echo off` as a general rule is bad advice, better advice would be to explain to OP _when_ to use it. In this particular script it is clear that the first block of code works, right up to the first pause. So after the `pause`, OP should turn `@ECHO ON` and continue from there. Your second rule is spot on though, and as OP did not include the actual error message I agree that they probably did not execute this from the command line.

Comment: thanks for all the help, I managed to get the game working!

Answer (score 2):

There are FIVE major syntax issues here preventing your batch file from executing.

1. To *get* | *access* | *use* the value of variables, you need to wrap the variable name with `%`, otherwise your cariable name will be interpreted as a string literal value that is equal to the variable name

   - In this following line, assume that the variable `shiponey` holds a value of `1`.

     ```
     IF shiponey == 1
     ```

     This will **NOT** evaluate to `TRUE`, because we have not told the compiler to use the value from our variable called `shiponey`, instead it is comparing the string "shiponey" to 1, which of course is not true.
   - Instead, wrap your variable in `%` to indicate you want to use the value of the variable in the expression.

     ```
     IF %shiponey% == 1
     ```
2. Your `IF` syntax is not complete, you can type `IF /?` into the command prompt for an explanation, but here are the general rules

   - IF is an *inline* statement, the next line break will terminate the expression. so your code is effectively executing `IF` expresisons and then doing nothing. The *command* to execute when the *expression* is `TRUE` must be the very next command on the same line

     ```
     IF %shiponey%==9 set /a shiponey=i
     ```
   - When you want to execute multiple statements, or you want to move your execution statement to the next line you need to use brackets to wrap all your expressions that correspond to the condition:

     ```
     IF %shiponey% == 1 (
         set /a shiponey=a
         goto ship two
     )
     ```

     Its not required in batch files, but I like to indent the code block that should be executed as a single expression.
3. Your `SET` expressions to convert the random *number* to a *letter* is using the `/a` switch, from the documentation `SET /?`:

   > The `/A` switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
   > is a numerical expression that is evaluated.

   So you should remove that, because your code is specifically trying to assign a string to the variable, not a number, all these epxressions will actually set the value of `shiponey` to `0` as the string literals are not numbers.
4. You have references to a label `ship two`, but your code does not define such a label. I will assume that the purpose of the `ship two` label was to break out of the `if` statements, given that only one of them would evaluate to `TRUE`

   - So you could define the `:ship two` at the end of the block that is translating the y ordinates into letters
   - Or you can chain the `IF` statements with `ELSE`

     - Although `IF` requires `ELSE` to be on the same line, it would make it harder to read in this case and importantly that option is not available to us because the `SET` command needs to use a new line to terminate it.
     - You must therefore use the bracket notation in this scenario too, even though there is only a single command to execute for each `IF` conditional expression, the trick is to make sure the `ELSE` is on the same line as the previous closing bracket, *and* that your next `IF` expression is immediately after it.

       ```
       IF %shiponey% == 1 (
            SET shiponey=a 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 2 (
            SET shiponey=b 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 3 (
            SET shiponey=c 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 4 (
            SET shiponey=d
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 5 (
            SET shiponey=e 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 6 (
            SET shiponey=f 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 7 (
            SET shiponey=g 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 8 (
            SET shiponey=h 
        ) ELSE IF %shiponey% == 9 (
            SET shiponey=i
        )
       ```

   While using *goto labels* is very powerful it can sometimes make the code harder to interpret. In this particular scenario I advise using *chained* or *nested* `IF` statements to make it clear that we are expecting a single command to be evaluated based on the value of `%shiponey%`.
5. When you are trying to *decrement* the value of `shots` you have used the `==` *equals comparison operator*, you will notice that you use this in `IF` expressions and it evaluates a *boolean* result from comparing the values on either side of the operator.

   - Instead you need to use the *single* equals sign, because it is the *assignment operator*:

     ```
     SET /a shots=%shots%-1
     ```

---

## Debugging Advice

When developing batch file scripts, it is helpful to evaluate them from a console session, either from PowerShell, or the command prompt. When you run your scripts from windows explorer when the program terminates the window will be automatically closed, when you run from a console the output, including the final termination message will remain in the console.

> You will notice that I have edited your original post to include the output, this was captured from a console session.

You script is failing with message `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` which by itself is not very helpful, if you turn the command `@ECHO` ON (the default state) then the all commands from your script will be printed on the screen with any error message immediately *before* the command is printed and the result of the command printed immediately *after* the command if it has any console output.

In your script you have disabled the command echo feature using `@ECHO OFF`. Which I understand because you want don't want the user to see your code, but we can and *should* turn it back on for the sections of the code that we want to debug.

For instance, you like what you see for everything up to the first `pause` but after that you don't know which line of code is causing problems, so immediately after the `pause` add a new line with:

```
@ECHO ON
```

Now after the pause you will see the following output:

```
 please allow some time while the game is set up.
Press any key to continue . . .

D:\temp>set /a shiponey=31714 %10

D:\temp>set /a shiponex=1417 %10
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
D:\temp>if shiponey==1
D:\temp>
```

From this output you can see the final error message, immediately before the line that caused the error.

Once you have verified that individual lines execute as you expect, you can move the `@ECHO ON` line further down the file, you can even turn it off and on again as you need to for different blocks of code.

Because it is a game, we don't want to see the generated numbers, but I do still want to echo out the lines after that so I can debug, so you can do this:

### script fragment:

```
...

pause

:ship one
set /a shiponey=%RANDOM% %%10
set /a shiponex=%RANDOM% %%10

@ECHO ON

if shiponey==1
set /a shiponey=a
goto ship two

...
```

### output:

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 welcome to battle ships! this is the imaginary grid.
 in this simplified version of the game, you only sink an CPUs ships, but dont place your own...
 if you shoot outside of the grid, it WILL count as a shot. you have only limited shots, so be careful
 please allow some time while the game is set up.
Press any key to continue . . .
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
D:\Temp>if shiponey==1
d:\Temp>
```

Comment: It's a team effort :) I was just bored... and I was super convinced I was right ;)

Comment: It would be helpful if SO made a way for all posts to have a direct link to chat, not just when we overflow the comments.